# What is the difference between the symbols $\cap$ and $\setminus$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between $\cap$ and $\setminus$ symbols for operations on sets?

Comment: This is easy to just go and look up. If you have found a definition but are struggling with it, then say so and we can help. We're not your own personal Google.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Their definition is different:

- $A\cap B=\{x\mid x\in A\text{ and } x\in B\}$, we take all the elements which appear both in $A$ and in $B$, but not just in one of them.
- $A\setminus B=\{x\mid x\in A\text{ and } x\notin B\}$, we take only the part of $A$ which is not a part of $B$.

Amongst the different properties, the intersection ($\cap$) is commutative and associative while difference ($\setminus$) is not. Namely it is generally true that:

$$A\cap B=B\cap A\\ A\setminus B\neq B\setminus A$$

and similarly:
$$A\cap (B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap C\\ A\setminus(B\setminus C)\neq (A\setminus B)\setminus C$$

Answer (score 7):

Here is the [Wikipedia article on $\cup$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29), the [Wikipedia article on $\cap$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29), and the [Wikipedia article on $\setminus$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement).

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, the sets $A\cup B$, $A\cap B$, and $A\setminus B$ are defined as
$$A\cup B=\{x\mid x\in A\;\text{ or }\;x\in B\}$$
$$A\cap B=\{x\mid x\in A\;\text{ and }\;x\in B\}$$
$$A\setminus B=\{x\mid x\in A\;\text{ and }x\notin B\}$$
For example, if $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{3,4,5,6\}$, then 
$$A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},$$
 $$A\cap B=\{3,4\},$$
$$A\setminus B=\{1,2\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

(Answer to the edited question):

$\cap$ is for set intersection and $\backslash$ is for set difference. I'm sure you can look up the wikipedia entries for them. Here is a more descriptive example:

Suppose $A$ is the set of families with pet cats, and $B$ is the set of families with pet dogs. $A \cap B$ will consist of families with at least one cat AND at least one dog. $A \backslash B$ will consist of families with at least one cat but NO dogs.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$A\cap B = \{x|x\in A \land x\in B\}$$
$$A\setminus B = \{x|x\in A \land x\not\in B\}$$

from  here we can say:

$$A\cap B=A\setminus B^c=B\setminus A^c$$
$$A\cap B^c=A\setminus B=B^c\setminus A^c$$

where:

$$B^c=\{x|x\not\in B\}$$